# Turbo Assembler 16 BIT Encryption Binary File

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox, 16-bit

I am trying to encrypt binary file. But program does not encrypt anything and it gets errors when writing file on disk. So I dont get encrypted file on disk and program stucks with infinite loop printing unknown symbols. Can you help me out and fix code, please.

```
.286
.model small
.stack 100h
.DATA

  bufferSize EQU 255
  keyword db bufferSize DUP (0)
  fileContent db bufferSize DUP (0)
  fileNameIn db "INPUT.DOC", 0
  fileNameOut db "OUTPUT.DOC", 0
  fileNameDec db "DECRYPTED.DOC", 0
  bytesCountReadWrite dw 0
  inputms db "Please enter keyword", 0
  emptyinputmsg db "Console input is empty", 0
  cantCreateFileMsg db "Can't create file", 0
  cantWriteFileMsg db "Can't write file", 0
  cantReadFileMsg db "Can't read file", 0
  cantOpenFileMsg db "Can't open file", 0
  handler_input dw 0
  handler_output dw 0
  handler_decrypt dw 0
.CODE
InitSet MACRO
    mov ax, @data   ; Load the segment address of the data segment into AX
    mov ds, ax      ; Set the data segment register (DS) to the value in AX
    mov es, ax      ; Set the extra segment register (ES) to the value in AX
;    xor ax, ax      ; Clear the value in AX by performing an XOR operation with itself
ENDM

GetStrLen MACRO string, strlen
    LOCAL count_bytes, end_count
    pusha
    push si             ; Save SI register on the stack
    mov si, OFFSET string ; SI = offset of the string
    ; Calculate the number of bytes to write
    mov cx, 0              ; Initialize byte count to 0
    count_bytes:
        cmp byte ptr [si], 0  ; Check if end of string
        je end_count          ; If end of string, jump to end_count
        add cx, 1             ; Increment byte count by 1
        add si, 1             ; Move to the next byte
        jmp count_bytes       ; Jump back to count_bytes to process the next character
    end_count:
        mov strlen, cx   ; Store the byte count in the memory location pointed by strlen
        pop si                    ; Restore SI register from the stack
        popa
ENDM
PrintString MACRO string
  LOCAL strlen
  .data
  strlen dw 0
  .code
  GetStrLen string, strlen
  pusha
  mov dx, offset string         ; Load the offset of the string to print into DX
  mov cx, strlen                ; Load the length of the string into CX      
  mov ah, 40h                   ; Set AH to 40h for writing to file or device
  mov bx, 1                     ; Set BX to 1 for standard output handle
  int 21h                       ; Call MS-DOS interrupt 21h to write the string
  popa
ENDM


ReadFileGetReadMsgLen MACRO filename, bytesRead, s, handler_input
  LOCAL readcontent, rt, closeFile, exit_readingfile 
  pusha
  ; check opened file
  mov ax, [handler_input]
  test ax, ax
  jnz readcontent
  ; getting filename
  lea bx, filename
  inc bx
  mov al, [bx]
  xor ah, ah
  add bx, ax
  inc bx
  xor al, al
  mov [bx], al
  ; open file
  lea dx, filename
  add dx, 2
  mov ah, 3dh
  xor al, al
  int 21h
  ; ax - filehandler or error num
  jnc readcontent ; check open error
  PrintString cantOpenFileMsg
  jmp exit_readingfile
readcontent:
  mov [handler_input], ax
  mov bx,ax ; read file
  mov ah, 3fh
  mov cx, bufferSize ; count
  lea dx, s
  int 21h
  jnc rt ; - open,write,read
  PrintString cantReadFileMsg
  jmp exit_readingfile
rt: ; if we read less than buffersize we can close file
  cmp ax, bufferSize
  jne closeFile
closeFile: 
  mov bytesRead, ax
  xor ax, ax
  mov ah, 3eh ; closing file handle
  int 21h
  mov [handler_input], ax
exit_readingfile:
  popa
ENDM



WriteFileGetWriteMsgLen MACRO keyword, filename, bytesWrote, str_chunk, handler_output
LOCAL writecontent, encodeContent, rtwrt, closeOutFile
  pusha
  push si
  ; Check opened file
  mov ax, [handler_output]
  test ax,ax
  jnz writecontent
  ; Getting filename
  lea bx, filename
  inc bx
  mov al, [bx]
  xor ah,ah
  add bx, ax
  inc bx
  xor al,al
  mov [bx], al
  ; Create File
  lea dx, filename
  add dx, 2
  mov ah, 3Ch
  xor cx, cx
  int 21h
  jnc writecontent 
  PrintString cantCreateFileMsg
  jmp closeOutFile
writecontent:
  mov [handler_output], ax
  lea si, str_chunk
  ;mov cx, word ptr [str_chunk]
  
  encrypt keyword, str_chunk
  mov bx, [handler_output] ; Write file
  mov ah, 40h
  ;mov cx, [str_chunk] 
  GetStrLen str_chunk, cx
  lea dx, str_chunk
  int 21h
  jnc rtwrt
  PrintString cantWriteFileMsg
  jmp closeOutFile
rtwrt:
  cmp ax, bufferSize
  jne closeOutFile
closeOutFile: 
  mov bytesWrote, ax
  xor ax, ax
  mov ah, 3eh ; Close file
  mov bx, [handler_output]
  int 21h
  xor ax, ax
  mov [handler_output], ax
  popa
ENDM


findX0 MACRO keyword, key0
    LOCAL search_loop, strlen
    .data
    strlen dw 0
    .code
    pusha
    GetStrLen keyword, strlen
    mov al, 0            ; Initialize AL register to 0
    mov bl, 0            ; Initialize BL register to 0
    mov cx, strlen   ; Load the length of the keyword into CX
    mov bx, offset keyword  ; Load the offset of the keyword into BX
    search_loop:
        mov al, [bx]     ; Move the byte at memory location pointed by BX into AL
        add key0, ax     ; Add the value of AX to key0
        rol key0, 8     ; Rotate the bits of key0 to the left by 8 positions
        inc bx           ; Increment BX to point to the next character in the keyword
        loop search_loop ; Decrement CX and repeat the loop until CX becomes 0
    popa
ENDM

encrypt MACRO keyword, message
    LOCAL encrypt_loop, X0, Xi, strlen, encryptedMessage, A, B, M   ; Define local labels for the loop and Xi variable
    .data
    encryptedMessage db bufferSize DUP (0)
    strlen dw 0
    Xi dw ?                  ; Define a word-sized variable Xi
    X0 dw 0
    A EQU 12
    B EQU 25
    M EQU 56
    .code
    findX0 keyword, X0
    GetStrLen message, strlen
    pusha
    push si                  ; Save SI register on the stack
    push di                  ; Save DI register on the stack
    mov ax, X0               ; Move the value of X0 into AX
    mov Xi, ax               ; Move the value of AX into Xi variable
    mov cx, strlen
    mov si, offset message   ; Load the offset of the message into SI
    mov di, offset encryptedMessage  ; Load the offset of the encrypted message into DI
    encrypt_loop:
        mov ax, [si]         ; Move the word at memory location pointed by SI into AX
        xor ax, Xi           ; XOR the word with Xi
        mov [di], byte ptr ax  ; Move the result byte by byte into the encrypted message
        mov ax, Xi           ; Move the value of Xi into AX
        mov bl, A         ; Move the value of Akey into BL
        mul bl               ; Multiply AX by BL
        xor bx, bx           ; Clear BX register
        mov bl, B         ; Move the value of Bkey into BL
        add ax, bx           ; Add BX to AX
        xor bx, bx           ; Clear BX register
        mov bl, M         ; Move the value of Mkey into BL
        div bl               ; Divide AX by BL
        xor bx, bx           ; Clear BX register
        mov byte ptr Xi, ah  ; Move the remainder into Xi
        xor ax, ax           ; Clear AX register
        inc si               ; Increment SI to point to the next word in the message
        inc di               ; Increment DI to point to the next byte in the encrypted message
        loop encrypt_loop    ; Decrement CX and repeat the loop until CX becomes 0
    xor ax, ax
    mov al, encryptedMessage ; Swap messages to return encrypted message
    mov message, al          ; Being stored into origin
    pop di                   ; Restore DI register from the stack
    pop si                   ; Restore SI register from the stack
    popa
ENDM
ReadString MACRO str
LOCAL ReadStringLoop, EndReadString, RetryInput, EndInputLabel
RetryInput:
    mov cx, bufferSize ;max input length for string limited to 255 due 
    mov dx, offset str ;place string itself
    push cx     ; save registers
    push si
    push cx     ; save digit count again
    mov  si,dx      ; point to input buffer
    dec  cx     ; save room for null byte 
ReadStringLoop: 
    mov  ah, 1       ; function: keyboard input
    int  21h        ; DOS returns char in AL
    cmp  al, 0Dh     ; end of line?
    je   EndReadString     ; yes: exit
    mov  [si], al        ; no: store the character
    inc  si     ; increment buffer pointer
    loop ReadStringLoop     ; loop until CX=0
EndReadString: 
    mov  byte ptr [si], 0        ; end with a null byte
    pop  ax     ; original digit count
    sub  ax, cx      ; AX = size of input string
    dec  ax     
    pop  si     ; restore registers
    pop  cx
  ; Check if zero length str
  xor ch, ch
  mov cl, [str+1]
  test cl, cl
  jnz EndInputLabel
  PrintString emptyinputmsg 
  jmp RetryInput
EndInputLabel:
ENDM

ReadingFile PROC
  ReadFileGetReadMsgLen fileNameIn, bytesCountReadWrite, fileContent, handler_input
  RET
ENDP
WritingFile PROC
  WriteFileGetWriteMsgLen keyword, fileNameOut, bytesCountReadWrite, fileContent, handler_output
  RET
ENDP

start:
  InitSet
  PrintString inputms 
  ReadString keyword
  encryptFileLoop:
    CALL ReadingFile
    CALL WritingFile 
    cmp bytesCountReadWrite, bufferSize 
    je encryptFileLoop
  mov ah, 4Ch ; Exit program
  int 21h
end start
```

I was trying to just read file but it stuck at infinite loop without writing anything back.

Comment: you should try to limit the amount of code that's problematic. Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question! By removing the code from the question you effectively render the answer that @Nassau provided meaningless. That's why I roll-backed the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How program works:

a) reads from console to buffer `keyword`

b) try to open `input.doc`, but there is no such file in folder. After `ah = 3dh`, `ax = 2`, file not found

c) writes to `output.doc` from `fileContent` buffer, which contains only zeros.

---

1. First problem occurs in `ReadFileGetReadMsgLen MACRO`. `bx` contains filename offset, but after that there is `inc bx`. So file name will be `(I)NPUT.DOC`. This code just puts `0` inside messages. So only part of text will appear on screen, because `0` marks end of string. `Can't creat` and `Can't wri`. Same code is in `WriteFileGetWriteMsgLen MACRO`.

   ```
    lea bx, filename    ; 0202h
    inc bx          ; 0203h
    mov al, [bx]        ; al = 4eh = 'N'
    xor ah, ah      ; ah = 0
    add bx, ax      ; bx = 0203h + 004eh = 0251h
    inc bx          ; bx = 0252h    
    xor al,al       ; al = 0
    mov [bx], al        ; [0251] = 0
   ```
2. Program can't open `INPUT.DOC`, because there is no file. Program should use service `5bh` at the begining of `ReadFileGetReadMsgLen MACRO` to create file or open existing file.
3. Service `3dh` works fine now because file was created with `5bh`
4. `dx` contains `(IN)PUT.DOC`. No such file exists.

   ```
   lea dx, filename    ; dx = 0202h
   add dx, 2       ; dx = 0204h
   mov ah, 3dh
   xor al, al
   int 21h
   ```
5. Service `3fh` reads 0 bytes because there is no data in file `input.doc`. Maybe idea was to read from console to `keyword` buffer and save this to file `input.doc`. I added proc which does that `Keyword2InputFile`.
6. And then read from `INPUT.DOC` to `fileContent` buffer. Well, program could just copy `keyword` to `fileContent`.
7. `WriteFileGetWriteMsgLen MACRO`. Same problems as above.
8. `Encrypt MACRO`, `mov al, encryptedMessage`, `mov message, al`, it's just insertion of one byte `4b`, I think code should
   return offset to `encryptedMessage` in `dx`, because we use dx service `40h` after encyption.
9. Inside `GetStrLen str_chunk, cx`, `cx = 6` but `popa` restores old value. So only 2 bytes will be saved to `OUTPUT.DOC`. I used `di` here to store `str_chunk` length.

Code:

```
.286
.model small
.stack 100h

.DATA
  bufferSize EQU 255
  keyword db bufferSize DUP (0)
  fileContent db bufferSize DUP (0)
  fileNameIn db "INPUT.DOC", 0
  fileNameOut db "OUTPUT.DOC", 0
  fileNameDec db "DECRYPTED.DOC", 0
  bytesCountReadWrite dw 0
  
  inputms db "Please enter keyword: ", 0
  emptyinputmsg db "Console input is empty", 0
  cantCreateFileMsg db "Can't create file", 0
  cantWriteFileMsg db "Can't write file", 0
  cantReadFileMsg db "Can't read file", 0
  cantOpenFileMsg db "Can't open file", 0
  handler_input dw 0
  handler_output dw 0
  handler_decrypt dw 0
  
.CODE
InitSet MACRO
    mov ax, @data   ; Load the segment address of the data segment into AX
    mov ds, ax      ; Set the data segment register (DS) to the value in AX
    mov es, ax      ; Set the extra segment register (ES) to the value in AX
;    xor ax, ax      ; Clear the value in AX by performing an XOR operation with itself
ENDM

GetStrLen MACRO string, strlen
    LOCAL count_bytes, end_count
;    pusha
    push si             ; Save SI register on the stack
    mov si, OFFSET string ; SI = offset of the string
    ; Calculate the number of bytes to write
    mov cx, 0              ; Initialize byte count to 0
    count_bytes:
        cmp byte ptr [si], 0  ; Check if end of string
        je end_count          ; If end of string, jump to end_count
        add cx, 1             ; Increment byte count by 1
        add si, 1             ; Move to the next byte
        jmp count_bytes       ; Jump back to count_bytes to process the next character
    end_count:
        mov strlen, cx   ; Store the byte count in the memory location pointed by strlen
        pop si                    ; Restore SI register from the stack
;        popa
ENDM

PrintString MACRO string
  LOCAL strlen
  .data
  strlen dw 0
  .code
  GetStrLen string, strlen
  pusha
  mov dx, offset string         ; Load the offset of the string to print into DX
  mov cx, strlen                ; Load the length of the string into CX      
  mov ah, 40h                   ; Set AH to 40h for writing to file or device
  mov bx, 1                     ; Set BX to 1 for standard output handle
  int 21h                       ; Call MS-DOS interrupt 21h to write the string
  popa
ENDM

ReadFileGetReadMsgLen MACRO filename, bytesRead, s, handler_input
  LOCAL readcontent, rt, closeFile, exit_readingfile 
  
  ;fileNameIn, bytesCountReadWrite, fileContent, handler_input
  
  pusha
  ; check opened file
  mov ax, [handler_input]
  test ax, ax
  jnz readcontent
  
  mov ah, 5bh                   ; create file
  lea dx, offset filename
  mov cx,2
  int 21h
  
  cmp ax,50h                    ; file exists?
  jne save_file_handle          ; new file created
  jmp file_exists
  
  save_file_handle:
    mov [handler_input], ax
  
    mov bx,ax
    mov ah, 3eh ; closing file handle
   int 21h
   
   file_exists: 
  ; getting filename
;  lea bx, filename             ; INPUT.DOC
;  inc bx                       ; NPUT.DOC
;  mov al, [bx]
;  xor ah, ah
;  add bx, ax
;  inc bx
;  xor al, al
;  mov [bx], al
  
  ; open file
  lea dx, filename
;  add dx, 2
  mov ah, 3dh
  xor al, al
  int 21h
  ; ax - filehandler or error num
  jnc readcontent ; check open error
  PrintString cantOpenFileMsg
  jmp exit_readingfile
  
readcontent:
  mov [handler_input], ax
  mov bx, ax ; read file
  mov ah, 3fh
  mov cx, bufferSize ; count
  lea dx, s             ; read to fileContent
  int 21h
  jnc closeFile     ; data saved in input.doc, close file

  PrintString cantReadFileMsg
  jmp exit_readingfile
  
closeFile: 
  mov bytesRead, ax
  mov bx,[handler_input]
  xor ax, ax
  mov ah, 3eh ; closing file handle
  int 21h
;  mov [handler_input], ax
exit_readingfile:
  popa
ENDM

WriteFileGetWriteMsgLen MACRO keyword, filename, bytesWrote, str_chunk, handler_output
    LOCAL writecontent, encodeContent, rtwrt, closeOutFile
    
    ;keyword, fileNameOut, bytesCountReadWrite, fileContent, handler_output

  pusha
  ; check opened file
  mov ax, [handler_output]
  test ax, ax
  jnz writecontent
  
  mov ah, 5bh                   ; create file
  lea dx, offset filename
  mov cx, 2
  int 21h
  
  cmp ax,50h                    ; file exists?
  jne save_file_handle          ; new file created
  jmp file_exists
  
  save_file_handle:
    mov [handler_output], ax
  
    mov bx, ax
    mov ah, 3eh ; closing file handle
   int 21h
   
   file_exists: 
  ; getting filename
;  lea bx, filename             ; OUTPUT.DOC
;  inc bx                       ; UTPUT.DOC
;  mov al, [bx]
;  xor ah, ah
;  add bx, ax
;  inc bx
;  xor al, al
;  mov [bx], al
  
  ; open file
  lea dx, filename
;  add dx, 2
  mov ah, 3ch
  mov cx, 2
  int 21h

    jnc writecontent 
    PrintString cantCreateFileMsg
    jmp exit_writingfile
    
writecontent:
    mov [handler_output],ax
    lea si, str_chunk           ;filecontent buffer
    ;mov cx, word ptr [str_chunk]
  
    encrypt keyword, str_chunk
    mov bx, [handler_output] ; Write file
    mov ah, 40h
    ;mov cx, [str_chunk] 
    GetStrLen str_chunk, di
    mov cx, di
    ;lea dx, str_chunk
    int 21h
    jnc rtwrt
    PrintString cantWriteFileMsg
    jmp closeOutFile
    
    rtwrt:
        cmp ax, bufferSize
        jne closeOutFile
        
closeOutFile: 
    mov bytesWrote, ax
    xor ax, ax
    mov ah, 3eh ; Close file
    mov bx, ax
    int 21h
    xor ax, ax
    mov [handler_output], ax
    
    exit_writingfile:
    popa
ENDM

findX0 MACRO keyword, key0
    LOCAL search_loop, strlen
    .data
    strlen dw 0
    .code
    pusha
    GetStrLen keyword, strlen
    mov al, 0            ; Initialize AL register to 0
    mov bl, 0            ; Initialize BL register to 0
    mov cx, strlen   ; Load the length of the keyword into CX
    mov bx, offset keyword  ; Load the offset of the keyword into BX
    search_loop:
        mov al, [bx]     ; Move the byte at memory location pointed by BX into AL
        add key0, ax     ; Add the value of AX to key0
        rol key0, 8     ; Rotate the bits of key0 to the left by 8 positions
        inc bx           ; Increment BX to point to the next character in the keyword
        loop search_loop ; Decrement CX and repeat the loop until CX becomes 0
    popa
ENDM

encrypt MACRO keyword, message          ;1
    LOCAL encrypt_loop, X0, Xi, strlen, encryptedMessage, A, B, M   ; Define local labels for the loop and Xi variable
    .data
    
    ;keyword, str_chunk
    
    encryptedMessage db bufferSize DUP (0)
    strlen dw 0
    Xi dw ?                  ; Define a word-sized variable Xi
    X0 dw 0
    A EQU 12
    B EQU 25
    M EQU 56
    .code
    findX0 keyword, X0
    GetStrLen message, strlen
;    pusha
;    push si                  ; Save SI register on the stack
;    push di                  ; Save DI register on the stack
    mov ax, X0               ; Move the value of X0 into AX
    mov Xi, ax               ; Move the value of AX into Xi variable
    mov cx, strlen
    mov si, offset message   ; Load the offset of the message into SI
    mov di, offset encryptedMessage  ; Load the offset of the encrypted message into DI
    encrypt_loop:
        mov ax, [si]         ; Move the word at memory location pointed by SI into AX
        xor ax, Xi           ; XOR the word with Xi
        mov [di], al            ; or ax ah ??  byte ptr ax  ; Move the result byte by byte into the encrypted message
        mov ax, Xi           ; Move the value of Xi into AX
        mov bl, A         ; Move the value of Akey into BL
        mul bl               ; Multiply AX by BL
        xor bx, bx           ; Clear BX register
        mov bl, B         ; Move the value of Bkey into BL
        add ax, bx           ; Add BX to AX
        xor bx, bx           ; Clear BX register
        mov bl, M         ; Move the value of Mkey into BL
        div bl               ; Divide AX by BL
        xor bx, bx           ; Clear BX register
        mov byte ptr Xi, ah  ; Move the remainder into Xi
        xor ax, ax           ; Clear AX register
        inc si               ; Increment SI to point to the next word in the message
        inc di               ; Increment DI to point to the next byte in the encrypted message
        loop encrypt_loop    ; Decrement CX and repeat the loop until CX becomes 0
    xor ax, ax
    mov dx, offset encryptedMessage ; Swap messages to return encrypted message
;    mov msg_off, dx          ; Being stored into origin
;    pop di                   ; Restore DI register from the stack
 ;   pop si                   ; Restore SI register from the stack
;    popa
ENDM

ReadString MACRO str
LOCAL ReadStringLoop, EndReadString, RetryInput, EndInputLabel

RetryInput:
    mov cx, bufferSize          ;max input length for string limited to 255 due 
    mov dx, offset str          ;place string itself
    push cx                     ; save registers
    push si
    push cx                         ; save digit count again
    mov  si,dx                     ; point to input buffer
    dec  cx                     ; save room for null byte 
    
ReadStringLoop: 
    mov  ah, 1                  ; function: keyboard input
    int  21h                        ; DOS returns char in AL
    cmp  al, 0Dh                    ; end of line?
    je   EndReadString          ; yes: exit
    mov  [si], al                   ; no: store the character
    inc  si                     ; increment buffer pointer
    loop ReadStringLoop             ; loop until CX=0
    
EndReadString: 
    mov  byte ptr [si], 0        ; end with a null byte
    pop  ax                       ; original digit count
    sub  ax, cx                   ; AX = size of input string
    dec  ax     
    pop  si                   ; restore registers
    pop  cx
                                  ; Check if zero length str
    xor ch, ch                    ; First element of keyword is 0dh 
    mov cl, [str+1]
    test cl, cl
    jnz EndInputLabel
    PrintString emptyinputmsg 
    jmp RetryInput
    
    EndInputLabel:
ENDM

ReadingFile PROC
  ReadFileGetReadMsgLen fileNameIn, bytesCountReadWrite, fileContent, handler_input
  RET
ReadingFile ENDP

WritingFile PROC
  WriteFileGetWriteMsgLen keyword, fileNameOut, bytesCountReadWrite, fileContent, handler_output
  RET
WritingFile ENDP

start:
  InitSet                                   ; ok
  PrintString inputms                       ; ok
  ReadString keyword                        ; ok
  
  call Keyword2InputFile
  
  encryptFileLoop:
    CALL ReadingFile
    CALL WritingFile 
    cmp bytesCountReadWrite, bufferSize 
    je encryptFileLoop
  mov ah, 4Ch ; Exit program
  int 21h
  
Keyword2InputFile proc  
    pusha
    
    mov ah, 5bh                     ; create file
    lea dx, offset fileNameIn       ; INPUT.DOC
    mov cx, 2                       ; attrib rw
    int 21h
  
    cmp ax,50h                      ; file exists?
    jne new_file_created            ; new file created
    jmp open_input_file ; file already exits
  
    new_file_created:
        mov [handler_input], ax     ; save handle
        jmp copy_keyword_2_input_doc
        
   open_input_file:     
        mov ah, 3dh                 ; open file
        mov al, 2                   ; attrib rw     
        lea dx, fileNameIn
        int 21h
       mov [handler_input], ax     
   
   copy_keyword_2_input_doc:
        mov bx, ax 
        mov ah, 40h
        mov cx, bufferSize
        lea dx, keyword
        int 21h

    mov bx, [handler_input]
    mov ah, 3eh                     ; close file
    int 21h

    xor ax,ax
    mov [handler_input], ax
    popa
    ret
Keyword2InputFile endp  
end start
```